# ASP.NET Core - package Nuget packages on Save Changes and replace them with remote packages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Our company is currently developing the Continuous Integration process in Visual Studio Team Foundation Services and we've gotten to the part where we need to replace locally saved NuGet 
packages with the packages which have already been uploaded to the MyGet server (https://www.myget.org/).

We are currently investigating two things:

1. Is there any option in Visual Studio where the IDE detects and builds packages automatically (and that's only counting the projects in which I've done changes, not triggering the build for all of them)?
   Is there a way to save the packages locally to one root folder and not in the bin folder of each project? Please bear with me if the questions are silly, I'm still new to all of this.
2. What is the process of swapping the locally saved packages with the MyGet packages? Is there a task which can be added in VSTS? Should a PowerShell script be written for that process? 
   Any guidance will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Do you solve it with my way?

Answer (score 0):

First, the Visual Studio can’t detect and build package automatically if you’ve done changes.

Secondly, there are many ways to sync the packages, but the changes need to be pushed to server.

1. Publish NuGet packages to your MyGet server through [NuGet push task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget#push-nuget-packages) (add it to your CI build)
2. Do it in MyGet build directly when code is pushed to a Git repository in VSTS: [MyGet with Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/myget)